# PowerShell Output to CSV Not Placing Columns in Correct Order

Tags: powershell

How do I code this to output the columns in this order:

```
unique_sis_group_id, unique_sis_user_id, unique_sis_school_id, mm_admin
```

My code:

```
$objs = @();
$output = Import-Csv -Path "c:\users\patrick\desktop\RelayFiles\RelayMemberships\file2concatenate.csv" | ForEach {
    $Object = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        unique_sis_group_id  = [String]::Concat($_.unique_sis_group_id, $_.unique_sis_user_id)
        unique_sis_user_id = $_.unique_sis_school_id
        unique_sis_school_id = $_.mm_admin
        mm_admin = 0
    }
    $objs += $Object;
}
$objs
$objs | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation c:\users\patrick\desktop\RelayFiles\RelayMemberships\memberships.csv
```

Comment: if you use either an `[ordered]` hashtable OR [better] the `[PSCustomObject]` type accelerator, you will get your props in the declared order.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Note that both `[ordered]` and `[PSCustomObject]` are not available prior to PowerShell v3.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - ah! thank you for the reminder! [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign the `ForEach-Object` to `$output`, but nothing inside actually outputs something.
Using a `[PSCustomObject]` is much simpler:

```
## Q:\Test\2019\01\25\SO_54373962.ps1
$CsvIn  = "c:\users\patrick\desktop\RelayFiles\RelayMemberships\file2concatenate.csv"
$CsvOut = "c:\users\patrick\desktop\RelayFiles\RelayMemberships\memberships.csv"
$output = Import-Csv -Path $CsvIn | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
         unique_sis_group_id  = [String]::Concat($_.unique_sis_group_id, $_.unique_sis_user_id)
         unique_sis_user_id   = $_.unique_sis_school_id
         unique_sis_school_id = $_.mm_admin
         mm_admin             = 0
    }
}
$output
$output | Export-Csv $CsvOut -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thank you for the lesson. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This took care of it. Is there a better way?

```
$objs =@();
$output = Import-Csv -Path "c:\users\patrick\desktop\RelayFiles\RelayMemberships\file2concatenate.csv" | ForEach {
    $Object = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        unique_sis_group_id  = [String]::Concat($_.unique_sis_group_id, $_.unique_sis_user_id)
        unique_sis_user_id = $_.unique_sis_school_id
        unique_sis_school_id = $_.mm_admin
        mm_admin = 0
    }
    $objs += $Object;
}
$objs |
    Select-Object "unique_sis_group_id", "unique_sis_user_id",
        "unique_sis_school_id", "mm_admin" |
    Export-CSv -NoTypeInformation c:\users\patrick\desktop\RelayFiles\RelayMemberships\memberships.csv
```

Comment: For PowerShell v2 and earlier `Select-Object` is the way to go, because the `[ordered]` and `[PSCustomObject]` type accelerators have been introduced with PowerShell v3 and aren't available in earlier versions. If you have PowerShell v3 or newer use the `[PSCustomObject]` type accelerator as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54374494/1630171), which also avoids the pitfall of appending to an array in a loop.